# The trace of an affine transformation

Tags: trace, affine-geometry

Suppose V=
{
v
= (
$v_
1$
,$v_
2$
,$v_
3$
$)
^T$
$\in$
$\mathbb{R}$
$^3$
|
$v_
2$
= 0
}
and
W$
=
\mathbb{R}
^2$
. Furthermore (
A
,V,φ
) =
(
V,V,φ
) and (
B
,W,ψ
) = (
W,W,ψ
) the respective affine Spaces. The trace mapping is defined between the respective spaces is then defined as:

$Tr
f$ $\\$
:
V
→
W,

v
→
$(
v_
1,
v
_3
)^T$
$\\$

Determine f.

I am completely confused by this question but the exact formulation is the one I wrote above. First of all, I don't even know how a trace mapping can have two dimensions. Furthermore it is unclear whether $f$ is a linear mapping, but maybe I am overlooking something. Can someone shed some light on this mistery of a question ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the simpler interpretation of the question if to find the matrix of the transformation:
$$
(\nu_1,0,\nu_3)^T\to(\nu_1,\nu_3)^T
$$
and this is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&a&0\\
0&b&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Clearly the term ''trace'' here is not the usual *trace* of the matrix.